# I need to write it in resume/appraisal but don't know how to express it

Tags: syntactic-analysis

When I joined 3 people were working on the project, after 6 months it was handed to me alone and those three were assigned to different projects. I need to write it in resume/appraisal but don't know how to express it I asked a friend who suggested to write something like following:

> I increased FTE savings by consecutively handling the work (or work
>   load) of three.

Comment: I don't think 'consecutively' is quite the right word, as it suggests that you did the three people's work one after another.

Comment: What can the line be that is what I am trying to figure out. Thanks for replying...and i meant HANDLING not HADLING.

Comment: @ShashankSingh On this site, it's preferred to make corrections by [edit]ing the original directly instead of updating via comments. This allows future readers to read the question just once, instead of having to re-read it after going through the comments. Edit history is available from the link that appears to the left of your username block. Feel free to edit further or to roll back the changes.

Answer (score 1):

“by taking over the work previously done by a team of three”?